# Hide a <div> when conditions not given

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I want to hide a div on my wordpress website, if few rules are not given. I tried this so far:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'hideCalender' );
function hideCalender() {
  $checkout_page_id      = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
  if (is_page ('kasse')) { 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('wc-od').style.display='none';
    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should output the javascript instead of using in php.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'hideCalender' );
function hideCalender() {

    $checkout_page_id      = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
    if (is_page ('kasse')) { 

        echo '
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                document.getElementById("wc-od").style.display="none";
            });
            </script>
        ';

    }

}
```

Comment: Not working too.. Wordpress is not showing anything at all just a whitescreen with an error  message

Comment: Okay, the if statement is getting passed correctly but i get the error "document is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved with putting CSS between the if statement

```
$checkout_page_id      = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
  if (is_page ($checkout_page_id)) { 
    ?>
      <style>
        #wc-od{
          background-color: red !important;
        }

      </style>
    <?php
    }
```